# JBoss Add New DB Properties Files Without Restarting

Tags: java, jboss

I am currently working with a Java multi-tenant application running on JBoss.

Currently whenever we add a new customer we:

1- create a new database for them
2- add a new DB properties xml file on our JBoss node (a new file in 'deploy' directory)
3- restart Jboss

However, the restart is quite a drawback and I would like to eliminate this.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: What is your JBoss version?

Comment: We are running JBoss version 6.4